# Updating conda base - how to move to newer version?

Tags: python, conda

I was trying to update my conda base after a log message informed that a latest version is available.

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.12.0
  latest version: 4.13.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda
```

I am using the following

`conda update -n base conda=4.13.0`

is that going to break anything?

Comment: What is your setup? Are you using the base environment for any specific project or do you have (as recommended) seperate environments for each of your projects?

Comment: no I am running it as a container which will serve all users

Comment: I didn’t think `conda update` respects versions. If you want a specific version installed, use `conda install`.